# Is there better regex to calculate the number of Chinese letters and exclude some characters at the same time?

Tags: python, regex

I want to calculate the number of Chinese letters and exclude some characters, for example,

```
s_l = ['康熙十年','咸丰三年','民国二十二年']
```

need to exempt ‘年’ character,so

```
s_l = ['康熙十年','咸丰三年','民国二十二年']
for idx, str_item in enumerate(s_l):
    res = len(re.findall(r'[\u4E00-\u9FFF]', str_item))-len(re.findall(r'[年]', str_item))
    print(res)
```

Now, can I combine these two regex to one? If so, how? It is not easy to combine directly to

```
re.findall(r'[\u4E00-\u9FFF]((?![年]).)*$', str_item)
```

Comment: Do you really need regex for that?

Comment: @Corralien Actually, it is really too long about the limited characters, and I have know how to use for-loop to solve it,but it is a little reptitive than regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will become much simpler if you `pip install regex` and then use

```py
import regex
s_l = ['康熙十年','咸丰三年','民国二十二年', 'abc']
rx = regex.compile(r'[^\P{Han}年]')
print( [len(rx.findall(s)) for s in s_l] )
# => [3, 3, 5, 0]
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqs4PkfBViFa/emu7c/bZj7tbXy6c4u6jvrTSTue7NjwZEcnhPtsw8Sns/c@2dUDVAAiQYIK6olJyeqxXEUVQAPAhukl5@cWZOakahSpR8fFBFR7JObVApXGqmtyFRRl5pVoKETnpOZpFFXopWXmpSTm5GgUa2oqpOUXKRQrZOYpAJ0Sq6DJ9f8/AA) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hCnwmi/2). The `[^\P{Han}年]` regex matches any Chinese chars other than `年`.

The `re` compliant pattern is

```
(?!\u5E74)[\u2E80-\u2E99\u2E9B-\u2EF3\u2F00-\u2FD5\u3005\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303B\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\U00016FE2\U00016FE3\U00016FF0\U00016FF1\U00020000-\U0002A6DF\U0002A700-\U0002B738\U0002B740-\U0002B81D\U0002B820-\U0002CEA1\U0002CEB0-\U0002EBE0\U0002F800-\U0002FA1D\U00030000-\U0003134A]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hCnwmi/1). See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/hNhktm):

```py
import re
s_l = ['康熙十年','咸丰三年','民国二十二年', 'abc']
rx = re.compile(r'(?!\u5E74)[\u2E80-\u2E99\u2E9B-\u2EF3\u2F00-\u2FD5\u3005\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303B\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\U00016FE2\U00016FE3\U00016FF0\U00016FF1\U00020000-\U0002A6DF\U0002A700-\U0002B738\U0002B740-\U0002B81D\U0002B820-\U0002CEA1\U0002CEB0-\U0002EBE0\U0002F800-\U0002FA1D\U00030000-\U0003134A]')
print( [len(rx.findall(s)) for s in s_l] )
# => [3, 3, 5, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
exclude_list = list('?!.)ab')
for str_item in s_l:
    res = len([i for i in str_item if i not in exclude_list])
    print(f"{str_item}: {res}")
```

Output:

```
abc)def: 4
aaabbbccc: 3
dfg: 3
```

With a regex:

```
for str_item in s_l:
    res = len(re.findall(r'[^?!.)ab]', str_item))
    print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply again, but that is not I want...

Comment: So use: `re.findall(r'[^?!.)ab]', str_item)`

Comment: Or: `re.sub(r'[?!.)ab]', '', str_item)`?

Comment: Now, does it what you expect?

Comment: Another way: `re.findall('[cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]', str_item)`

Comment: @Probably there are another character, like +_*&...ect..,and I only want to get English char,[cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ] this one is not generalized, but thanks for your help

Comment: Your problem is not clear... I don't know why my last solution is not generalized? To build it, I used `import string; f"[{re.sub(r'[ab]', '', string.ascii_letters)}]"`

Comment: In fact, I need to find all Chinese characters and exclude some char like '年月日'，to this type: adding  r'[\u4E00-\u9FFF]' and deleting r'[年月日]', maybe I need clarity my problem...